# El compilador no identifica la función gets()

Tags: c, compilacion

El compilador me da un error `Wimplicit-function-declaration` y no entiendo por qué, ya que dispongo de las librerías necesarias.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <string.h>

typedef char  TTablaFrases[5][80]; //una tabla de 5 frases

void EscribirFrase (TTablaFrases tabla){


}


int main() {

    TTablaFrases miTabla;

    strcpy (miTabla[0], "Primera frase");
    strcpy (miTabla[1], "Segunda frase");
    strcpy (miTabla[2], "Tercera frase");

    int i;
    for (i=3; i<5; i++)
    {
        printf ("Escribe tu la siguiente frase\n");
        gets (miTabla[i]);
    }

}
```

Solo se queja de esa línea, el resto del código parece estar bien.

Comment: Al margen de que consigas hacer que te compile con `gets()`, lo recomendable es no usar esa función y utilizar `getline()`, `fgets()` u otra función equivalente. http://crasseux.com/books/ctutorial/gets.html

Comment: Gracias, desconocía esas funciones y en efecto han funcionado. ¿Debería eliminar la pregunta?

Comment: No la borres, es mejor si dejas una respuesta propia indicando cómo la has resuelto, así le puede servir a otra persona que en el futuro tenga el mismo problema que has tenido.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La función [`gets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/gets) definida en la cabecera `<stdio.h>` fue declarada como obsoleta en el estándar C99 y fue eliminada en el estándar C11. El motivo de esta decisión es que dicha función no hacía ninguna comprobación de límites sobre el puntero que recibía como parámetro, por lo que se consideraba una función muy vulnerable a ataques de desbordamiento de búfer.

Si pese a haber incluido la cabecera `<stdio.h>` el compilador te indica que la función no existe, eso significa que estás utilizando un compilador cuyo estándar es C11 o superior. Como alternativa puedes usar la función `fgets`:

```
for (int i = 0; i != 5; ++i)
    fgets(miTabla[i], 80, stdin);
```

Answer (score 1):

Aparentemente la función gets() está obsoleta y por ello puede dar bastantes problemas. Por lo tanto más allá de si el compilador es capaz de reconocerla, se recomienda el uso de otras funciones sustitutivas tales como getline() o fgets() tal y como han indicado en los comentarios.